# iOS - Facebook SDK 3.1.1 Build Fail armv7

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, armv7

I am about to integrate the Facebook SDK solely (at least for now) for the purpose of having mobile ads for my app shown in the Facebook app. I downloaded the latest SDK v3.1.1 and added the framework to the project. It does not build however and gives me this error:

[image]

I find it hard to believe that this framework was not compiled for armv7. Has anyone else had this error with the FacebookSDK? I am using iOS6 as my base SDK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you have to add a lot more than just the framework to your project. Once I followed this guide, it worked.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

Go to section 5 - Configure a New Xcode Project.

Answer (score 0):

In architectures also add armv7s along-with armv7 & then build your project.Hope this helps you.[image: here I attach image also add like this image]

Comment: Yea my project was already set up like that. My answer above solved the issue for me.